# how to save favourite list from the ListTile and show in favourite list?

Tags: flutter

i want to save list as favourite list on OnTab from the ListTile which i am fetching from  my api and want to show that favourite list to my favourite list in next page

Comment: If you have to store a data after the app closing, use database (for example - [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)). If favourites only needs in app session (without saving it and restore after another app start), you can create a static list for all screens and store entities in it.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) yess!  i want to do that second options. ..no i don't want to store a data after closing the app i just want to save in app session only can you please send me some sample of that code it will help me a lots thank you once again